# Connection refused to MongoDB installed on Ubuntu EC2 instance

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have 2 `EC2 AWS` instances, both are on `Ubuntu`.Both these instances are associated to 2 different subnets of the same VPC.
My application is installed on one instance(16.0.2.114) to which the **Elastic IP** is associated and `MongoDB` on the other instance(16.0.4.117).

What I am trying to achieve is that **I want my application on 16.0.2.114 to connect to the MongoDB on the 16.0.4.117** but I am getting the following exception:

> org.mongodb.driver.cluster -76: Exception in monitor thread while
>   connecting to server 16.0.2.114:27017 
>   com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
>   ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na]   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
>   ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na]   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
>   ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na]   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45] Caused by:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_45]    at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
>   ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na]   at
>   com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
>   ~[mongo-java-driver-3.0.2.jar!/:na]   ... 3 common frames omitted.

I have modified **bind_ip** of **mongo.conf** to listen to 16.0.2.114 and the security groups to listen to all the ports.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your VPC ACL allows inbound traffic on your mongodb port